# pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, types

I'm using `pandas.read_sql_query()` to read some data from database, one field `date` looks like this:

```
Date
9999-12-31 00:00:00
9999-12-31 00:00:00
9999-12-31 00:00:00
....
```

if I use

```
dtypes = {'Date': 'datetime64[ns]'}
df=pandas.read_sql_query(query, engine, dtype=dtypes)
```

This gave me an error:

> `pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00`

So I specified it to `str` in `dtypes`, then load the dataframe, then I did
`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`
I still get the same error.

Another thing is that no matter I use `dtypes = {'Date': 'datetime64'}` or `dtypes = {'Date': 'datetime64[ns]'}` or `dtypes = {'Date': 'datetime64[D]'}`, seems like there's no difference... Is it because `datetime64[ns]` is the standard data type in pandas?

Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: if it is ok for you that these dates are set to `NaT` ("not a value"), you can set kwarg "errors" to "coerce"; `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors="coerce")`. See also [Timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) in the pandas docs.